# Bind a List<DataTable> to a ListView with GridView in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

I have a List of DataTables I generate. This number of items in this list is variable. How do I bind the datasource of each of the gridview inside the listview to a datatable in this list? I have tried setting the datasource of the listview, but this doesn't help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the `List<DataTable>` to the `DataSource` property of the `ListView`. Then assign the `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property of the `GridView` in the [`ListView`'s `ItemDataBound` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        DataTable table = (DataTable) e.Item.DataItem;
        GridView grid = (GridView) e.Item.FindControl("GridViewID");
        grid.DataSource = table;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```